# Running Windows Service on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-server-2012-r2

I have written a Windows Service and have tested and debugged it on my own PC and it works! But when I deploy the service on the production server (Windows Server 2012 R2) the service won't work. The service starts and stops without any errors, but the service will not do anything after it is started. The service don't write anything in my log-file.

This what I have done so far on the server:

- Copied all the files from my local PC to the server (`.exe, .exe.config, .pdb, .vshost, .vshost.exe, .exe.manifest`and my own files`Settings.xml, EnvTest.txt`and`LogFile.txt`)
- The copied files are placed at `C:\SomeFolderName\` and I have written an install and uninstall `.bat` script.
- I have added the NETWORK SERVICE user with `Full Control` to the directory
- I am logged in as `Administrator`

Here is some info of the service

- The service gets data from a SQL SERVER 2012 Express database. The database lives on the same server as the service. The database is query-able from any applications (I have tested this!).
- The service adds logs to a log-file placed in the same directory as the service executable
- The service writes to a ASCII file, also placed in the same directory
- The service gets configuration from an XML-file, also placed in the same directory

So the overall picture is, that the service read/writes to a lot of files in the `C:\SomeFolderName\` directory.

I can't not understand why the service won't work on the server. Do I need to do anything?

If it makes any difference here is the code for my OnStart()

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    mainTask = new Task(PollDatabase, cts.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    mainTask.Start();
}
```

Let me know if you need more code.

Comment: Have you registered your service properly with the service install tool?

Comment: We can't reproduce this. There's nothing special about Windows Server 2012 and Windows Services on that OS. The problem must be in your code. Add more logging to make sure your logging works, and if that doesn't help, attach a (remote) debugger. Probably just some permission issue.

Comment: What happens if you run the application interactively?  Have you checked the server's event logs?